# Do I need to use "that" after to "think"?

Tags: conjunctions, that

In this phrase:

> I caught myself thinking **that** most people ...

Is "*that*" unnecessary or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the AP Style Guide,

> Use the conjunction *that* to introduce a dependent clause if the sentence sounds or looks awkward without it. ... When in doubt, include *that*. Omission can hurt. Inclusion never does. (252)

That said, as a copy editor, I was told to pretty much always remove "that," since it was hardly ever necessary.

In your case, it almost certainly isn't ...

> I found myself thinking most people [are able to smile normally].

... sounds fine to me, and I would have removed it were it sent to me for editing.

So, is it necessary? **No.**

Is it wrong? **No.**